# WPF MVVM parent child relationships

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a database with two SQL tables a SourceInspection Table and an InspectionStatus Table:

[image]

I brought the tables in as MVVM using the entity framework.

The SourceInspection table is displayed as a WPF datagrid.

I want to have a textbox column called "KeyColumn" and when the specific **deliveryID** in the sourceinspection table has a record in the inspection status table with a **documentID** of "ABC" then
I want to color the keycolumn orange.

I feel like the correct way to do this is with data binding and not looping through every item in code behind.  I think a datatrigger will be required so I created the following:

```xml
 <Window.Resources>
     <CollectionViewSource x:Key="SourceViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type  local:SourceInspection}, CreateList=True}" />
     <CollectionViewSource x:Key="InspectionStatusViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type  local:InspectionStatu}, CreateList=True}"/>

     <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" x:Key="ValidateStatus" >
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=InspectionStatusViewSource.DocumentID}" Value="ABC"/>
                </DataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"></Setter>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

I'm pretty sure that I don't have the binding correct.

1. Is this the correct approach or is code behind looping through lists required?  There could be multiple documentID's for a single deliveryID.

Any help on the XAML would be great.

Thanks in advance,

Kerry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intuition on using a `DataTrigger` here is good, just not the way you did it.

The binding you have works against a single `SourceInspection`, which is why yours doesn't work (`InspectionStatusViewSource` doesn't exist on that object). Moreover, having the trigger do the loop for you is a hidden performance hazard assuming you could get it to work.

I would recommend taking those two model objects and, in your view model or in a service, use LINQ to create a custom view model object that has pre-collated the document ids and such. This object would have an extra property (say `HasABC`) that the data trigger would then go off of.

You could create a calculated property on the EF object (same `HasABC`) but that would run each time the grid enumerates, so is less ideal overall.